# PostgreSQL grant select righs on function with no SELECT access to table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, sql-grant

I know how to grant only SELECT access to user on selected tables or views or even columns. On the other hand, I do not want them to be able to do SELECT column1, column2 FROM ..... Creating a view is not an option, since SELECT column1, column2 FROM view will do the exact same thing. On the other hand I have created a pgpsql function that requires two IDs and queries the same table but only retrieves a maximum two rows from the DB table (for id=ID1 AND id=ID2). Is there a way to limit a user to only use this function to query the table, while not giving him full SELECT rights on this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to give privileges on the table to the `OWNER` only; this is the default behaviour in PostgreSQL.

You can then create a function with `SECURITY DEFINER` which means that the function is executed with the privileges of whomever created the function. If that is the same user as the owner of the table, then that part is done.

All that is now left is to `GRANT EXECUTE` on the function to whomever needs access to the data.

Comment: Excellent. So I define the function as the owner of the DB table and I use SECURITY DEFINER on the function definition. Then I grant execute this function to the limited user. This way the limited user may query the Db table through this function and still the limited user has no SELECT privileges on the DB table. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. By default, only the owner of a table has access to it. By granting the `EXECUTE` privilege on a function with a `SECURITY DEFINER` clause, that limited user can execute the function ( as may be expected), but the access to the table is performed by the owner of the function. If that owner is also the owner of the table then all is fine, otherwise the table owner should `GRANT SELECT` to the owner of the function.